# thymeleaf does not replace variables

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm new to thymeleaf so sorry if it's dummy question. I would like to create a 'hello world' with thymeleaf 3.
I would have to operate with templates which are stored in database and I only can get them as a text.

I have read that I need to use StringTemplateResolver in order to achieve that.

I made an example but it does not replace my variable ${user} and I do not understand where I have made mistake.

```
// define TemplateEngine
TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
StringTemplateResolver templateResolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

String htmlTemplate = "<b>${user}</b>";
Context context = new Context();
context.setVariable("user", "Ray Donovan");

String res = templateEngine.process(htmlTemplate, context);
System.out.println(res); // it prints out: <b>${user}</b>
```

Could somebody highlight that to me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reported in the official documentantion [Thymeleaf #text-inlining](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#text-inlining):

> Expressions between [[...]] are considered expression inlining in
>   Thymeleaf, and in them you can use any kind of expression that would
>   also be valid in a th:text attribute.

Said so, you have to use the double square bracket notation.
Instead of `<b>${user}</b>` you should use `<b>[[${user}]]</b>`.

Answer (score 6):

You can refer to [`@araknoids`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46709475/3094731) answer or update your `htmlTemplate` to

```
String htmlTemplate = "<b th:text="${user}"></b>";
```

Comment: thanks, it works even though it looks weird for me :-).
I have to accept araknoid answer since he was first.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan had also that idea but didn't know if it worked also on `<b>` tags. Always used the square notation in this situation.

Comment: Matter of preferences. I have always used `th:text`. Looks less cluttered :)